# static product page with jquery and sqlite / json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, sqlite

i have to build a static product page which is working on a usb-stick. To build this page, i can only use JS and HTML, no PHP or something else.

The first page is a page with 3 categories. If I'm choosing one of this categories, I should see the next page with some subcategories. A click on a subcategory should show me some products from this category. A click on a product should show me some product details. This is all, it should be possible to go back to the previous page by Icons in the frontend.

Generally this is all what is needed.

I don't wanna create many of static pages with the same markup, I thought i could manage this with jquery, and json or sqlite. - but i need a starting point.

I thought to build the needed code for the static pages and include it in 1 html page. Then I would hide the not needed elements and show the start page with the categories. If someone clicks on a category, I would hide the category page and show the subcategory page and fill it with data from "JSON / sqllite"? the same procedure could be use for showing the product details.

At the moment I've no idea how to get this working. I hope someone could give me a starting point to solve this problem. Maybe if there is a tutorial or something else for a similar problem. I haven't found one so far.

I also build some "Example Code" if it is need to demonstrate a solution:

```html
<!-- CATEGORY PAGE PART -->
<div id="categoryPage">
  <h1>Category Page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="category1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="category2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="category3">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- SUBCATEGORY PAGE PART -->
<div id="subCategoryPage">
  <h1>Category 1 - Subcategorys:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="subcategory1">Subcategory 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcategory2">Subcategory 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcategory3">Subcategory 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="">back to category listing</a>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT PAGE PART -->
<div id="productPage">
  <h1>Subcategory 1 - Products:</h1>
  <p>Our Products</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="product1">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="product2">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="product3">Product 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="">back to subcategory listing</a>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT DETAIL PART -->
<div id="productDetailPage">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <dl>
    <img src="img/productimage.jpg" alt="image">
    <dt>Title 1</dt>
    <dd>Description 1</dd>
    <dt>Title 2</dt>
    <dd>Description 2</dd>
    <dt>Title 3</dt>
    <dd>Description 3</dd>
    <a href="">back to product listing</a>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a single page app (SPA) without learning any of the SPA frameworks like [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) you may look into this tutorial that uses just jQuery and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for templates:

http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/

The tutorial uses JSON for product data input, so the app can run offline (or on a usb-stick if you wish).

Some more information about Single Page Applications by John Papa here:

http://www.johnpapa.net/building-single-page-apps-with-knockout-jquery-and-web-api-ndash-the-story-begins/

Comment: Hi, I've tried to use the tutorial listed, but I've problems to use the json data. Could you please take a look at it? I made a bin: http://jsbin.com/ceyitutoso/1/edit?js,output Hope you can help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a "complete" answer, but a good start in terms of UI. You'd still need to get JSON and populate the list items accordingly. Hope that helps.

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2r5o0bug/1/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".category").on("click", "li", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        var nextCategory = $(this).closest(".category").data("nextCategory");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/', //href or the desired URL
            dataType: 'json' // or the desired data type
        }).done(function(jsonData) {
            //do stuff with your data here
            //update categories etc.
            //then diplay the next page/section
            $(".category").addClass("is-hidden")
            $("#" + nextCategory).removeClass("is-hidden");
        });
    }).on("click", "a[data-prev-category]", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var prev = $(this).data("prevCategory");
        $(".category").addClass("is-hidden");
        $("#" + prev).removeClass("is-hidden");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- CATEGORY PAGE PART -->
<div id="categoryPage" class="category" data-next-category="subCategoryPage">
  <h1>Category Page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="category1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="category2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="category3">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- SUBCATEGORY PAGE PART -->
<div id="subCategoryPage" class="category is-hidden" data-next-category="productsPage">
  <h1>Category 1 - Subcategorys:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="subcategory1">Subcategory 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcategory2">Subcategory 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcategory3">Subcategory 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-prev-category="categoryPage">back to category listing</a>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT PAGE PART -->
<div id="productsPage" class="category is-hidden" data-next-category="productDetailsPage">
  <h1>Subcategory 1 - Products:</h1>
  <p>Our Products</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="product1">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="product2">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="product3">Product 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-prev-category="subCategoryPage">back to subcategory listing</a>
</div>
<!-- PRODUCT DETAIL PART -->
<div id="productDetailsPage" class="category is-hidden">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <dl>
      <img src="img/productimage.jpg" alt="image" />
    <dt>Title 1</dt>
    <dd>Description 1</dd>
    <dt>Title 2</dt>
    <dd>Description 2</dd>
    <dt>Title 3</dt>
    <dd>Description 3</dd>
    <a href="#" data-prev-category="productsPage">back to product listing</a>
  </dl>
</div>
```